# Markdown converts embed/iframe HTML into non-usable HTML

Tags: python, html, django, markdown

This:

```
<embed type="text/html" src="https://example.com/" width="100%" height="100%">
```

gets converted into this (when rendered on the page):

```
<p> &lt;embed type="text/html" src="https://example.com/" width="100%" height="100%"&gt; </p>
```

making the embed tag unusable. Is there are any way to stop this from happening?
The same happens when you use an iframe tag. I expect the page "example.com" to be rendered.

I'm using Django for the project and have the following displaying the Markdown:

```
{{ page.text | escape | markdown | safe }}
```

with `page.text` being the variable holding the text.

The version of [Markdown](https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/) I'm using is 3.2.

Comment: It works just fine for me, both using the command-line interface and the programmatic interface. Please [edit] your question to show us how you're trying to convert the file.

Comment: @Chris I've now edited the question to include code which displays the markdown, however, there isn't anything more to add. Django is the framework being using for the system and the extra code added is what displays the information

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention Django before. What value does `page.text` have? Is it that whole `embed` tag? Why are you using [the `escape` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#escape)? Its whole point is to escape HTML, e.g. to convert `<` to `&lt;`, which doesn't make much sense if you're then using the `safe` filter.

Comment: If this question gets reopened I'll add a proper answer, but this ☝️ is the issue.

Comment: @Chris That's the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using Django for the project and have the following displaying the Markdown:
>
> ```
> {{ page.text | escape | markdown | safe }}
> ```

Assuming `page.text` contains the `<embed>` you show in your question, your problem is your use of [the `escape` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#escape).

Its job is to escape HTML code, which includes converting `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` as you are seeing. Once that conversion has been made, neither the `markdown` nor the `safe` filter will change it back.

It doesn't make a lot of sense to use `escape` and then [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe), as `safe` simply prevents autoescaping.

The right solution depends on the source of your `page.text`. If you trust that source, you can take `escape` out of your template. **Note that this *does* open the door for security issues from malicious users or accidental misuse, e.g. by [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).**

If you don't trust the source, you have two main options:

- Use `escape` and accept that any HTML content contained in `page.text` won't work.
- Skip `escape`, but run your HTML through a more granular sanitizer after the Markdown step, similarly to [what GitHub does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44831715/354577). See also [Best practice for allowing Markdown in Python, while preventing XSS attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359237/354577)